# Changing servers, and getting SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character parsererror

Tags: php, parsing, syntax-error, json

I'm moving php code from one linux server to another, and the new one is producing rubbish.

In Firebug, the first result looks great, like normal json encoded values, and works.

The second result (new server) is preceded by "html" and "body" tags, a "p" tag, and then "quot;" instead of actual quotes around the data (sorry, I couldn't get the form to display all that), and throws an error.

In both cases, the code is the same, the output an array passed through json_encode.

Could this be a configuration error?

Thanks in advance.

John

Comment: are the PHP versions same on both the servers?

Comment: Is the "new" server maintained by you, or is it a php webspace hosting service?

Comment: The old server is running PHP 5.3.5.  The new one is running 5.3.10.

Comment: Both servers belong to clients.  I have more control over the new one.

Comment: I also tried a test: $a=array(1, 2, 3);
echo json_encode($a);  The result was surrounded by "html", "body" and "p" tags, still

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, ultimately I added header('Content-type: application/json'); which removed the encoded html.  I'd sure like to know why I had to do that.